# Need help to design banner using Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new in using Jetpack compose. How can I design the following banner using jetpack compose with horizontal scroll & dot indication?

[image: banner.png]

I was trying to do so, but my result is not expected. A jetpack composable function with compose code is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Pager to achieve the desired behavior.

Example:

```kotlin
val pageCount = 10
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

HorizontalPager(
    pageCount = pageCount,
    state = pagerState
) { page ->
    // Our page content
    Text(
        text = "Page: $page",
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    )
}
Row(
    Modifier
        .height(50.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
) {
    repeat(pageCount) { iteration ->
        val color = if (pagerState.currentPage == iteration) Color.DarkGray else Color.LightGray
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(2.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .background(color)
                .size(20.dp)

        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Check the documentation with examples at: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/pager